# looking for "invertibility and singularity"

Tags: soft-question, spectral-theory

*Dear* *friends*

Many monts ago,i searched a lot the book of Robin Harte "invertibility and singularity".

this book contains a lot of demonstrations that i need in my master.
it focus on banach algebras,boundaries,connected hulls.
It seems to be very helpfull.

I did not find it for free .

Is there someone who can share me a link to download it for free?

Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about your department's library? Don't you have some research fund to buy these things?

Comment: our department's library is new and our country do the best but Tunisia my country is  unfortunately  poor

Comment: I see...is there any chance you could write directly to the author or to the editor and ask them to help you out. I know I myself, when having some postal interchange with some authors, have received very graciously from some of them free copies of their books...